# Why isn't the output match with my expected output? Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I tried to add the string elements to the dictionary but it doesnt work

```
adatok = ["marha", 1, "kacsa", 2, "kacsa", 1, "birka", 3, "marha", 4, "marha", 2]
sorszámok = list(set([x for x in adatok if type(x) == int]))


szótár = {}
for i in sorszámok:#Létrehozzuk a sorszámokat egy szótárba
    szótár.update({i:set()})

for j in adatok:
    if type(j) == int:
        szótár[j].add(adatok[adatok.index(j)-1])
#Expected output:{1: {'marha','kacsa'}, 2: {'kacsa','marha'}, 3: {'birka'}, 4: {'marha'}}
#Output:{1: {'marha'}, 2: {'kacsa'}, 3: {'birka'}, 4: {'marha'}}
```

Comment: `adatok.index(j)` gives the *first* index of `j` in your list. If you want the index at the position your for loop has reached, use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for your for loop.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting with unique keys and then trying to find the values for each key, iterate over the `key, value` pairs and add them to the sets.  Using `defaultdict` saves you the trouble of setting up the dict ahead of time.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> adatok = ["marha", 1, "kacsa", 2, "kacsa", 1, "birka", 3, "marha", 4, "marha", 2]
>>> szótár = defaultdict(set)
>>> for k, v in zip(adatok[1::2], adatok[0::2]):
...     szótár[k].add(v)
...
>>> dict(szótár)
{1: {'marha', 'kacsa'}, 2: {'marha', 'kacsa'}, 3: {'birka'}, 4: {'marha'}}
```

Comment: The problem is, that it only works if the 3: should be {"birka"}, what if the key 3 should be {"birka","marha"}?

Comment: Add `"marha", 3` to the end of your list before building the dict and you'll see `"marha"` get added to the `3` set.